# fscanf type function for streams?

Tags: c++, file-io, iostream, fstream

I'm used to using fscanf for simple file input, because it makes it simple.  I'm trying to move to streams though and I'd like to be able to do this:

```
fscanf(file, %d %s, int1, str1);
```

as you can see it's relatively easy to read through a file, stick the first int you come across into one container, and then the first string into a char*.  What I want, is to do this with fstreams, using stream functions.  This is what I came up with, with my limited stream knowledge.

```
while((fGet = File.get() != EOF))
{
    int x;
    int y;
    bool oscillate = false;
    switch(oscillate)
    {
    case false:
        {
            x = fGet;
            oscillate = true;
            break;
        }
    case true:
        {
            y = fGet;
            oscillate = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I want to scan through a file and put the first int into x, and the second into y.

This is pretty bad for a few reasons, as you can tell, and I'd never actually use this but it's all I can think of.  Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Why in your initial description have an int and a char*, but two `int`s in your pseudocode?

Comment: @Matt, because.  That's really it lol.  I just felt like being different.

Comment: @MooingDuck: although I generally agree with the solution I want to point out that if `str1` is declared `char*` you definitely want to use something akin to `if (in >> int1 >> std::setw(size) >> str1) { ... }`. Sure, the use of `fscanf()` has a similar problem but I think it is important to note that input to `char*` is essentially equivalent to `gets()` unless its size is constraint.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Correct, I failed to recall that the string parameter was a `char*` and not a `string`.  Jcrack: use a `std::string`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To read two integers from a stream, all you have to do is

```
int x, y;
File >> x >> y;
```

And the equivalent of

```
fscanf(file, "%d %s", &int1, str1);
```

Is

```
int x;
string s;

file >> x >> s;
```

And make sure that if you want to check whether the reads worked, put the reads in the condition:

```
if (file >> x >> s)
```

or

```
while (file >> x >> y)
```

or whatever.

Comment: Really?  It's that easy?  Well that's simpler than I thought it had to be.  Thanks

Comment: @Jcrack: Reading and writing in the default ways with streams is easier than printf.  If you want to format... it's MUCH more verbose, but easier to understand.  C++ works to make programming easiser and less error prone than C.

Comment: I see... so the >> operator will automatically type cast for me?  What if I need it to read a bunch of numbers into a char or stream instead?  How shalt this be accomplished?

Comment: A char can only hold one number, what did you mean there?

Comment: @mooing, sorry.  I mean a single number into a char, or a bunch into a string.

Comment: @Jcrack a number into a `char`? A `char` can also hold letters. But it's the same as the above: `char c; cin >> c; string s; cin >> s;`